# cannot parse json with $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have a code like

```
$('#letter-b').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.getJSON('b.js', function(data,status){
     $('#dictionary').html(data.term+" - "+status);
     }
  );
});
```

Where `b.js` is like

```
[
    {
        "term": "BACCHUS",
        "part": "n.",
        "definition": "A convenient deity invented by the...",
        "quote": [
        "Is public worship, then, a sin,",
        "That for devotions paid to Bacchus",
        "The lictors dare to run us in,",
        "And resolutely thump and whack us?"
        ],
        "author": "Jorace"
    }
]
```

But when I hit the button I get `undefined - success`.

Why I get `undefined`? How I must alter my syntax to get the value? I remeber that when I have a key-value pair, I have to use the incoming data (`data`) and then the name of the key (`term`) to get the value. I also tried `data[term]` and `data["term"]`, still nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: Your JSON parsing is most likely fine. You are just not reading the correct element afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

The JSON you are getting back is actually *an array that **contains** an object*. You'll need to reference the first index of the array to access the actual data:

```
$.getJSON( 'b.js', function( data, status ){
   var obj = data[ 0 ];
   $( '#dictionary' ).html( obj.term + " - " + status );
   }
);
```

Here is a small explanation of the structure contained within the response:

```
[  // data
    { // data[ 0 ]
        "term": "BACCHUS", // data[ 0 ].term
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: "an array that contains an object." Aha, makes sense now. Thank you so much. It worked

Comment: @user2860857 - happy to help! You might want to consider changing the format (if possible) and remove the array wrapping the data if it's not actually being used.